# Django is not sending email after rest-auth registration

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

After I changed user model to using email instead of username, email is not sending when I access `rest-auth.registration.views.RegisterView`.

What should I do to make working?

My email setup is:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```

It's correct configuration, sending email on `rest_auth.views.PasswordResetView` works fine.

### My code:

**users/urls.py:**

```py
app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path("register/", include("rest_auth.registration.urls")),
    ...
]
```

**config/urls.py:**

```py
from allauth.account.views import AccountInactiveView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("api/v1/users/", include("myproject.users.urls")),

    # this url is used to generate email content
    # https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/demo/demo/urls.py
    path("password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/", TemplateView.as_view(), name="password_reset_confirm")

    # for some reason required for rest-auth register view working
    path("account-inactive/", AccountInactiveView.as_view(), name="account_inactive"),
]
```

**config/settings.py**

```py
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

After accessing register view, there's no error. User object is created and response (code 201) is:

```
{
  "detail": "Verification e-mail sent."
}
```

However there's no email sent.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The problem occurred because default value for `is_active` field in `User` model was `False`. And for some reason `allauth` and `rest-auth` do not allow to send activation email for inactive user.