# django rest-auth registration returns "verification email sent" but no email gets delivered and no key sent / returned

Tags: email, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am new to **django, django-rest-framework, django-allaut and dj-rest-auth**. I am using postman to register a user, the user gets saved successfully in the database, and I get a message saying

```
{
    "detail": "Verification e-mail sent."
}
```

My email configurations is as follows (Both did not work in sending the email verification):
First tried

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailtrap.io'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = {{my_mailtraip_user}}
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = {{my_mailtraip_pass}}
EMAIL_PORT = '2525'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then tried:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = {{my_gmail_address}}
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = {{my_gmail_password}}
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

in my projects app, urls.py:

```
path('api/accounts/', include('account.urls')),
path('api/accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

accounts app urls.py:

```
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path(
        'dj-rest-auth/registration/',
        include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')
    ),
    path('dj-rest-auth/account-confirm-email/',
        VerifyEmailView.as_view(), 
        name='account_email_verification_sent'
    ),
```

settings.py

```
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
REST_USE_JWT = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    ...

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'dj_rest_auth',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
   "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

What am I missing or failing to understand? Why is the email not sent to mailtrap? Why am not getting the key?
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from [PolishCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310531/django-is-not-sending-email-after-rest-auth-registration)

Initially I thought it was due to some mis-configuration.